# Can't find PHP documentation for how SimpleXMLElement cast to array works

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I've seen code that takes a `SimpleXMLElement` object and casts it to array, eg.

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($file);
$arr = (array)$sxe;
```

but I can't find any PHP documentation for the `(array)` part.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(array)` notation is just a `cast` - in PHP jargon it's called [Type Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

In this case, it casts the response of [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) (which is of type `object`) to an array.

What happens in this case is described [in this section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of the PHP documentation:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
> elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
> names, [...]

I recommend you to output the casted array and just see what you've got

```
var_dump($arr)
```

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly thought casting to array would be done by the object itself. Thanks for the clarification and especially the link.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest using standart PHP ways for that. Instead I would recommend using [serializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer) library. It is quite easy to use IMO.

It allows different types of conversions. I myself used it for `Xml` => `Object` binding. Works as a charm. But as fas as I know it also allows such conversion type, that you need.